# Adding plugins inside HTMLField in Django-CMS 4.1

Tags: django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I am struggling adding plugins  inside `HTMLField`  as `djangocms-text-ckeditor` in the latest version `Django-Cms 4.1.0rc4` add `fileimage` plugin/button in the toolbar of it.

In my `models.py`

```
class PortfolioItem(CMSPlugin):
    # Attributes - Mandatory
    title = models.CharField(_('title'),
                    max_length=200, 
                    blank=False)

    content = HTMLField()
```

In the `settings.py`

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
 
    'content': {
        'name' : _('Content'),
        'plugins': ['TextPlugin', 'LinkPlugin', 'FilerImage'],
        'default_plugins':[
            {
                'plugin_type':'TextPlugin',
                'values':{
                    'body':'<p>Great websites : %(_tag_child_1)s and %(_tag_child_2)s</p>'
                },
                'children':[
                    {
                        'plugin_type':'LinkPlugin',
                        'values':{
                            'name':'django',
                            'url':'https://www.djangoproject.com/'
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        'plugin_type':'FilerImage',
                        'values':{
                            'name':'django-cms',
                            'url':'https://www.django-cms.org'
                        },
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
}
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    'language': '{{ language }}',
    'toolbar': 'CMS',
    'toolbar_HTMLField': [
        ['Undo', 'Redo'],
        ['cmsplugins', '-', 'ShowBlocks'],
        ['Format', 'Styles'],
    ],
    'skin': 'moono-lisa',
}
```

I can not get the list of plugins and fileimage button does not show up. How do I get the plugins inside nested editor?

ps: in the console i am getting

```
bundle-9f0bbac8ec.cms.ckeditor.min.js:25 [CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-plugin-deprecated. {plugin: 'flash'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't add plugins in an HTML field.

But what you can do is have child plugins, so that `PortfolioItem` can contain other plugins.

The main option on your plugin configuration is [`allow_children`](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#cms.plugin_base.CMSPluginBase.allow_children) which will allow you to nest other plugins within an instance of your plugin.

You can also restrict the plugins which can be nested, using [`child_classes`](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#cms.plugin_base.CMSPluginBase.child_classes). Similarly, a plugin can have `parent_classes` defined to only allow it to be a child of those given parent plugin classes.